# How to make a filter that is picking data from JSON in ionic 2 rc3

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript2.0

In my app I have JSON data with date. I want to show the data in day vice i.e., Today, yesterday etc. and I have a status called completed and pending. I wrote the ion-segment, in that segment I have completed and pending. I want to show the completed data in completed segment and pending data in pending segment.

[image]

Json Data Example with what my app will work.

```
`[{
    "day":"Today",
    "name":"Sandra Adams",
    "phno":8452514521,
    "tests": "Ecma, Hcbc...",
    "status":"pending"
}, {
    "day":"Yesterday",
    "name":"Nathan Jones",
    "phno":8452457845,
    "tests": "Ecma, Hcbc...",
    "status":"completed"
}]`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `Pipe` for that.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'anyPipe'
})
class AnyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(values: any[], day: string) {
    if (!values || !values.length) return [];
    if (!day) return values;
    return values.filter(v => v.day === day);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<list-item *ngFor="let item of (items | anyPipe:'Yesterday')"></list-item>
```